# Why setting alpha on ViewGroup makes child views transparent

Tags: android, xml, layout, alpha

I'm trying to understand how alpha affects the children of a viewGroup.

I've the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/mount"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_view"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/first_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_view">

        </View>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/first_view"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </View>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Following is the result

[image]

Why does setting alpha on the `RelativeLayout` makes the children transparent but the child views that're stacked on top of each other are still `opaque` and I don't see the RED view showing through the Green View in overlapping region. I'd love to understand why is this happening and how setting alpha on viewGroup affect its children?

Comment: Why would it? Alpha affects how `RelativeLayout` is drawn, not its children. As far as they're concerned they still end up clipping each other. Also rendering non opaque views (with alpha) is an expensive operation, just use transparent background colors.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401686/why-do-child-views-inherit-the-alpha-value-from-parent-layout) would help you

Comment: @Pawel but why do children inherit the alpha of the RelativeLayout? If the views are opaque, they should stay opaque even if the parent viewGroup is transparent. I'm just trying to understand how they're drawn and inherit the transparency

Comment: @Zain thanks for the link but it doesn't explain why don't child views retain their opaqueness rather then showing the viewGroup's transparency?